# Vorticity versus Viscosity

Tags: fluid-dynamics, terminology, viscosity, vortex

For a work project I need to revive my aerodynamics knowledge again. Can somebody help me with the distinction between [vorticity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorticity) and [viscosity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity).

If a flow vorticity is not equal to zero, the flow is called rotational and the flow elements have a finite angular velocity. But does this also imply the flow is viscous. And vice versa, if viscosity is taken into account, can a flow be irrotational?

Answer (score 1):

Vorticity describes whether the flow is rotational - that is, if you follow a path along the flow and return to the same point, is the net velocity zero or finite. This is expressed with the curl ($\nabla \times$) operator. This is a property of the flow.

Viscosity is a property of the medium, not the flow. Most fluids have viscosity - that is, if there is a velocity gradient in the flow, this will set up a shear stress which tends to try to counter the gradient.

An interesting side effect of viscosity is that it allows you to set up vorticity in a liquid - when there is no viscosity, "stirring" a liquid will cause no net vorticity.

Comment: Is your last statement correct even if one cheats and forces, say, an inviscid fluid to rotate (assume the fluid is bound by cylindrical geometry)?  In that case, would you not have $\nabla \times \mathbf{V}$ $\neq$ 0?  By "cheat" I mean we insert fan-like blades that force the fluid to move in a circular motion.  Are the blades too much of a "cheat" here or am I missing a simple concept?

Comment: @honeste_vivere - I think that what you describe cannot be called "stirring" any more (at least not in the sense I used the word). Similarly if you aim a jet of liquid along the tangent of a cylindrical container you can create vorticity - but that is not stirring _per se_. The idea is that if liquid can escape past the ends of the object doing the stirring, it will do so in a way that prevents you from imparting net vorticity.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  Under those conditions, I agree that inviscid flow will stay inviscid.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Getting clearer. What do you mean by 'if you follow a path along the flow and return to the same point, is the next velocity zero or finite'? Why return to the same point and does the 'next velocity' mean relative velocity?

Comment: @Ruudc - I think Floris was referring to part of Helmholtz's theorem about the conservation of vorticity flux.  There we have $\int \ dA \ \hat{n} \cdot \nabla \times \mathbf{V}$ (= $\int \ dA \ \hat{n} \cdot \boldsymbol{\omega}$) = $\oint d\mathbf{l} \cdot \mathbf{V}$.

Comment: @Ruudc - honeste_vivere is right. And there was a typo... I meant to say "net" not "next". Autocorrect on my phone, I'm afraid.